# jvm-libp2p how to achieve programs communicating over pubsub on the level of go-ipfs or js-ipfs nodes?

Tags: p2p, ipfs, libp2p

- if we connect two jvm-libp2p hosts to a public ipfs node and send pubsub messages between them - messages are not passed
- only if we connect them directly they receive each other's pubsub messages - but this defies the purpose of pubsub
- however - with js-ipfs or go-ipfs running two or more peers and subscribing to a topic is enough to almost instantly have message exchange between them, even if isolated with no mDNS - so that it is clear that messages go through IPFS network and remote peers

how to achieve the same on jvm?

Comment: similar issue https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/gossip-between-go-libp2p-jvm-libp2p/13599

Comment: similar issue https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/current-state-of-java-support/6607